# Orthogonality of wavefunction and overlap integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Is the following statement true? "If the overlap integral between two wavefunction is zero, then the two wavefunction are orthogonal."

An example would be two hydrogen atoms located far apart: their s orbitals don't overlap due to spatial separation. Is it valid to claim the two s orbitals are orthogonal?

(So this mean orthogonality is not solely determined by the phase/symmetry of the wavefunction but also the spatial separation.)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you mean by overlap. Specifically, support in real space or inner product? But hopefully I can answer anyway.

To be clear, if you have two H atoms, the full wavefunction describes *both* electrons and protons, and there is only one.

If we ignore interactions between the two H atoms, then that wavefunction is just a tensor product of two H-atom wavefunctions, and there is no notion of orthogonality between the wavefunctions for each atom, because they belong to different Hilbert spaces. They may overlap in real space, but they're functions of different electron's coordinates so the inner product is zero. The two orbitals are not orthogonal, just unrelated.

If we don't ignore the interactions, then we don't know how to solve this problem exactly, but we'd have to construct new orbitals. You could imagine perturbing about the limit in which the two H atoms don't interact, and this would lead to some mixing of the orbitals for the constituent atoms so that the state of the electron for the first hydrogen atom has some overlap with the states of the electron for the second, in which case the "overlap" would not vanish in the sense of *either* the inner product or real space.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the difference between "orthogonal" and "unrelated". I did not realize the two orbitals belong to different Hilbert spaces.  That is important.  Is it safe to conclude that if two systems are not interacting, they belongs to different Hilbert space, but once there is interaction connecting the two, they belongs to the same Hilbert space?

Comment: Maybe to be rigorous / careful, I would say that these two cases would have the *same* Hilbert space, which is a tensor product of the constituent Hilbert spaces for A and B. It's just that, without interactions between A and B, the full state is always a product state over the Hilbert spaces for A and B. But with interactions, generic states will have entanglement between the two Hilbert subspaces.

Comment: But yeah, without interactions, the orbitals for the distinct H atoms belong to different subspaces of the full Hilbert space. Which is the more mathy way to say "unrelated."

Comment: Let me see if I understand your point correctly: 1. the Hilbert space of each hydrogen atom is a subspace of the the full Hilbert space of the entire system-just like a large matrix that has two block matrices lie on the diagonal.  
Therefore instead of <s1|s2>=0, where S is just the s orbital of the hydrogen atom 1 or 2, and claim that |s1> and |s2> are orthogonal. It's more rigorous to say that <s1,0|0,s2>=0.  So |s1,0>,|0,s2> are the states that are orthogonal in the composite Hilbert space, correct?

Comment: Now if we add interaction to the system, there will be off-diagonal terms on the full matrix so the states are no longer orthogonal. Is my understanding correct?
Sorry about my long comments, you have been very helpful, thank you a lot!

Comment: Yes that is all correct, and happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

The [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of an atomic wavefunction is never compact. This implies, for example, that the overlap of the wavefunctions of two hydrogen atoms, even very far apart, is never exactly zero. Thus, two s-orbitals centered on the two atoms are not exactly orthogonal.

Comment: I totally agree with you, strictly speaking no two s orbitals have zero overlapping. But as the separation becomes larger, the overlapping integral is asymptotically approaching zero. This means they can still be treated as orthogonal if we take the limit of d$\leftarrow\infty$?